# Groovy closure - what is happening in this code?

Tags: groovy, closures

As a beginner groovy developer, I am trying to understand the following lines of groovy code I've inherited:

```
maxCount = skillsDist.findAll {it.mValue.value >= 0 }.max { it.mValue.value }.mValue.value
minCount = skillsDist.findAll { it.mValue.value >= 0  }.min { it.mValue.value }.mValue.value
```

The `skillsDist` object is a reference to a Java object of type `Set<CalculationResult>`.  Each `CalculationResult` has an `int` field `mValue`.

The part I am struggling with is the closures after the max and min.  Obviously, I am guessing it finds the min and max values out of the set but I need to modify this and am uncomfortable not understanding this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `findAll` iterater over the `set`. It creates a new `set` and adds all elements with a value bigger or equals than 0. The max operation iterates trough the subset and searches the maximum value.

The same in the second line (expect it looks for the min value).

Comment: Great!  Thank you!  I now see my problem was not understanding that the max operation was iterating.